# MobileFirst - JavaScript Adapter calling Java Adapter via REST endpoint

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server

This question is related to - [How to invoke Java adapter from HTTP adapter? ][1]

I have 2 adapters in my MobileFirst 7.1 project :

1. A Java Adapter that is exposing Rest Endpoint.
2. A JavaScript adapter will call the Java Adapter via Rest Endpoint

To be exact, this is what I call in the JS adapter :

```
function JSAdapterCalltoJavaAdapter() {
    var input = {
        method : 'get',
        returnedContentType : 'xml',
        path : "adapter/JavaAdapterRestPath"
    };
    return WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
 }
```

We have run JMeter load test for 800 Threads on Java Adapter, there is no issue. However, when we run load Test on JS Adapter, the MobileFirst server stop responding, and does not accept incoming request from JS Adapter. The new requests timeout and the MobileFirst console become unresponsive. When we stop the load test, the server gradually recovered.

I have configured the following params adapter.xml :
`<connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds>, <socketTimeoutInMilliseconds>, and <maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode>`

It seems like there is threading issue when using JS adapter to call Java adapter under load.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to open a PMR (support ticket) if you are encountering a threading issue in the MobileFirst Server so that the support/dev team could help you. If you have an actual *programming question*, ask it.

Comment: Thank you. Will open a ticket.

Comment: @CharlieYau Any solution for this issue? Mind to share it here?

Comment: Our final resolution is wrapping a JS adapter on a Java Adapter. This method has some issue, such as the Java Endpoint cannot be protected. The Java endpoint has to be block from the Firewall/Gateway perspective. The performance is not impacted, but there are some tuning required if you are using WAS Liberty 8.5.5.5